# Manipulating a bytearray stream

Tags: java, inputstream, bytearrayinputstream

I read the following string from command line(example):

```
abcgefgh0111010111100000
```

I process this as a stream to arrive at the first position which is a binary( in this case it is position 9).
The code is as follows:

```
String s=args[0];
    ByteArrayInputStream  bis=new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
    int c;
    int pos=0;
    while((c=bis.read())>0)
    {
        if(((char)c)=='0' || ((char)c)=='1') break;
        pos++;
    }

bis.mark(pos-1);\\this does not help
    bis.reset();\\this does not help either
    System.out.println("Data begins from : " + pos);
    byte[] arr=new byte[3];
    try{
    bis.read(arr);
    System.out.println(new String(arr));
    }catch(Exception x){}
```

Now the Arraystream would start reading from position 10('1').
How do I make it recede back by one position to actually start reading again from the first binary digit('0') at position 9.
`bis.mark(pos-1)` or reset does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow `bis.mark(pos-1)`, with `bis.reset()`.

reset() will position the stream's read cursor at the last marked position (`pos-1` in this case.)

From doc:

> Resets the buffer to the marked position. The marked position is 0 unless another position was marked or an offset was specified in the constructor.

Rewrite your loop like so:

```
String s = "abcgefgh0111010111100000";
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
int c;
int pos = 0;
while (true) {
    bis.mark(10);
    if ((c = bis.read()) > 0) {
        if (((char) c) == '0' || ((char) c) == '1')
            break;
        pos++;
    } else
        break;
}
bis.reset();// this does not help either
System.out.println("Data begins from : " + pos);
byte[] arr = new byte[3];
try {
    bis.read(arr);
    System.out.println(new String(arr));
} catch (Exception x) {
}
```

This code stores the position of the last read byte. Your code wasn't working before because it was storing the position *after* the byte you wanted was read.

Comment: Doesnt help - added this to the end and it starts printing from the second binary rather than the first.

bis.mark(pos-1);
 bis.reset();
 System.out.println("Data begins from : " + pos);
 byte[] arr=new byte[3];
 try{
 bis.read(arr);
 System.out.println(new String(arr));
 }catch(Exception x){}

Comment: Edited. That's how you need to use it.

Comment: Doesnt work either - in this case too,the stream has already read the first binary;and cant be made to recede by a position.

Comment: I tested your code with that exact loop and it seemed to work. In 8 or 10 hours I'll test it again for you. See if I made a mistake somewhere. Bed time, see you tomorrow :)

Comment: Edited again. That loop works, you probably didn't remove the `mark` call after the loop. Try my exact code above. It will work.